# SwiftUI TextField Simple Example not working

Tags: swift, textfield, swiftui

I tried to create a very simple TextField in SwiftUI but I cannot get it to work and I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Xcode gives me an error message that says:

"Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate."

I am not sure what to do.  I found some other code examples for TextFields with SwiftUI on StackOverflow but keep getting the same error.

```swift
struct TextFieldExample : View {
    @State var email: String = "Enter email address"
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField($email)
            Text("Your email is \(email)!")
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
struct ButtonTextField : View {
    @State var text: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField($text,
                      placeholder: Text("type something here..."))
            Button(action: {
                // Closure will be called once user taps your button
                print(self.$text)
            }) {
                Text("SEND")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Expected results = working TextField
Actual result = Error in Xcode

Comment: What is the purpose of declaring that `TextField` struct? You're effectively redeclaring SwiftUI's native `TextField`.

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56545737/8272698

Comment: @JulianSilvestri I saw the other example you linked to but it also gives me an error in Xcode that says "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'TextField' with an argument list of type...

Comment: @Russian I just want to have a working TextField example and I have not managed to either create one or get one to work from all the code samples I have found online.  Xcode 11 is always showing an error message.

Comment: i think your error is due to you having a view declared as your text view. why not just have the same view and add TextField in your hstack

Comment: That error is just because XCode 11 is still in beta. It has a lot of trouble inferring (guessing) the return types of the views in the SwiftUI. Unfortunately, in my experience, the only ways to fix the error are to clean the build folder and try rebuilding, closing and reopening the project in Xcode, wrapping multiple views in a custom view, or explicitly declaring the types by creating the views in a function that returns the exact view type (this can get ugly really fast if you add modifiers (`.background` `.frame` etc.) to the views that you are returning).

Comment: Also as many other comments have said, do not name any custom views the exact same as built in views. It will only confuse the compiler more.

Comment: @RPatel99 thanks.  Naming the example TextField was bad.  I changed the file name to TextFieldExample.swift.  Xcode is still throwing errors.  MIght be due to the beta nature of things.

Comment: @RPatel99 Thanks!  Your solution worked for me!  Should have tried closing and relaunching Xcode much sooner!  Always a good idea if things don't work with a beta app!

Comment: No problem! And welcome to SO!

Answer (score 4):

It seems the TextField view has been changed in a recent beta release. You should be able to create one using something like this:

```
struct MyView {
    @State var myInput: String = ""
    var body: some View {
      TextField("placeholder text", text: $myInput)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the recent beta release of Xcode TextField has been changed.

```
@State var email: String = ""

    var body: some View {
       TextField("Email", text: $email, onEditingChanged: { (isChanges) in
           // On Editing Changed
       }) {
           // On Commit
       }
       .padding(.leading, 13).padding(.trailing, 13).padding(.top, UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height / 2)
       .textContentType(.emailAddress)
       .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle.init())
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all do you really need to combine these Views into a custom view? If yes than:

1. `@State` and `BindableObject` should be passed into the view to the property marked with `@Binding` keyword
2. Don't use the same name as some of the native classes have

   ```
   struct MyTextField : View {

   @Binding var email: String

   var body: some View {
       VStack {
           Text("Your email is \(email)!")
           TextField($email, placeholder: Text("Enter your email"))
       }
     }
   }
   ```

Call it like this

```
@State private var email: String = ""

var body: some View {
    MyTextField(email: $email)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TextField like SearchView - **XCODE 11.3**

```
struct SearchBarV: View {

     @State var text: String = ""
     var onEditingChanged: (Bool) -> Void = { _ in }
     var onCommit: () -> Void = { }

     var body: some View {

         GeometryReader { metrics in
             TextField("placeholder", text: self.$text, onEditingChanged: self.onEditingChanged, onCommit: self.onCommit)
            .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.1))
            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0.0, leading: 16.0, bottom: 0, trailing: 16.0))
            .frame(width: metrics.size.width, height: 50)
            .keyboardType(.emailAddress)
        }

    }
}


 struct SearchBarV_Previews : PreviewProvider {
     static var previews: some View {
        SearchBarV()
     }
 }
```